# Should I consider false(default value) for feature like geo-enabled that are missing valu?

Tags: twitter, dataset, data-mining

I have twitter data set and in some feature that are boolean, values are not set while default value for this feature in twiiter are false or zaro e.g geo-enabled or protected... so should I consider false or zero fo these feature??

Answer (score 0):

If there is a default value, then a missing value should be replaced with the default value, obviously.

Because that is how the data format is defined, isn't it?